# Showing images based on a figure using php

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a university project and I have a page will a php calculator where users enter '$valuea' which is likely to be between 0-550 then they will hit submit which subtracts '$valueb' which is 250, giving them '$answer'.

What I need help with is I was to have a particular image echo out once the user hit submit, which depends on the figure of $answer.

```
So if $answer is between 0-149 = $image1 is shown
if $answer is between 150-249 = $image2 is shown
if $answer is between 250-349 = $image3 is shown
if $answer is between 350-449 = $image4 is shown
if $answer is between 450-549 = $image5 is shown
```

The images are all in the database and each have a unique URL.

Can anyone help me with the required php to make this happen?

Comment: If you're on an university you should be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: I'm not doing computer science, I do more graphic design however this is a side piece of my course

Answer (score 0):

This is like the most basic PHP you can imagine...

```
<?php
if( $answer > 0 and $answer < 150 )
   echo $image1;
elseif( $answer < 250)
   echo $image2;
elseif( $answer < 350)
   echo $image3;
elseif( $answer < 450)
   echo $image4;
elseif( $answer < 550)
   echo $image5;
else
   echo 'error';
?>
```

If you want to learn more about if/elseif/else, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: Thanks I'm an amateur, I was also looking for the full page, so how do I retrieve the image form the database?

Comment: That's based on your database, with a query most likely `$image = mysqli_query("SELECT image FROM database WHERE param='value');"`